# Some translated strings do not take effect

Tags: bug, localization, international-sites

With the site update, some translated strings have been "discarded".

We've re-added the new translation, but the changes don't take effect.

[Bug report on ja.SO meta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3649)

> "$count$ questions with new activity"

> $minutes$ mins ago

> Add a comment

> Enter at least $min$ characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I confirmed that this problem has been resolved as of 2022-02-02.

[image]

[image]